# JQuery selector : How to get a img id that have an one and only one attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

For example, if only one of the image on the page has attribute aria-disabled = "true" , how to use a jquery selector to get this element ? And notice that not all the images have aria-disabled , some of them don't have this attribute and some of them have aria-disabled = "false". Only **one** image has aria-disabled = "true". Thanks

eg.

```
$(img :  aria-disabled = "true").attr(id);
```

Of course this should be invalid synatx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$('img[aria-disabled="true"]').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Element Selector (“element”)](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) and [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) documentation.

You can combine the element and attribute selector by concatenation

```
$('img[aria-disabled="true"]').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

***HTML***

```
<div>
     <img aria-disabled="true" id="1">
     <img aria-disabled="flase" id="2">
</div>
```

***JS CODE***

```
$img = $('img');
if($img.attr('aria-disabled') == 'true'){
    alert($img.attr('id'));
}
```

**OR**
    this also more effective

```
$('img[aria-disabled="true"]').attr('id');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCTgY/)**